# Conflict in GCC version display

Tags: linux, shell, gcc, command

In Linux machine, multiple versions of GCC are currently installed.
To find out the current GCC version the below command is executed.

```
$ gcc --version
```

It displayed, 
**gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)**

When the command 'gcc --version' is executed through a shell script, it is displaying a different gcc version.

The script content:

```
VERSION=$(gcc --version)
echo ${VERSION}
```

The display is, 
   **gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.**

If the same shell contents are executed on command line it is showing different version of GCC.

```
$VERSION=$(gcc --version)
$echo ${VERSION}
```

It shows,
 **gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)**

For the same command, it is displaying two different version of GCC, strangely. What could be cause of conflict?

Comment: `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Could you show the content of `PATH`, both from the shell and from the script?

Comment: The **'echo $PATH'** is showing same content via 'command line' and through 'shell script' as **'/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/test/bin:'**

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible that your current shell and your script using different setting of `PATH`. If you put a `echo $PATH` before both your `gcc --version` command, you will see the difference.